# Access - How to change the combo box default value in a subform from a mainform

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I have a combo box called `unit` which holds a value list(`kgs`,`lbs`). I want all my `unit` combobox default value in my subform to change to the mainform `unit` current value.

Here my current code which doesn't seem to be working. 
I get #NAME in the combo box.

I'm able to MsgBox the Me.unit.Value without any problem, but I can't seem to do the subform. I get this fallowing error message.

```
Private Sub unit_AfterUpdate()
    Me!frm_addReceiveReportDetailsSubForm.Form!unit.DefaultValue = Me!unit.Value
    Me!frm_addReceiveReportDetailsSubForm.Requery
    MsgBox "DefaultValue: " & Me!frm_addReceiveReportDetailsSubForm.Form!unit.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: First, I assume your code is located in the main form? Second, do you want to update the list of available values in the combobox, or just set the selection to match?

Comment: Make sure you're calling the forms and their controls the way you [should be](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

Comment: I just want to change the default value with `kgs` or `lbs` which both combo box in the main and subform have in their value list.